# pairwise adding element in a tuples of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two list of tuples

```
[[1,3000],[2,5000],[3,7000],[4,10000]]
[[1,2000],[2,3000],[3,4000],[4,5000]]
```

the sum is 10000. Here we have [2,5000],[4,5000] and [3,7000],[2,3000] so the output should be **[2,4]** and **[3,2]**

```
[[1,2000],[2,4000],[3,6000]]
[[1,2000]]
```

the sum is 7000. Here since I dont have a combination that sum up to 7000 I consider all the possible combinations 4000(2000+2000),6000(4000+2000) and 8000(6000+2000) and consider the next lowest number from the desired sum which is 6000 . For 6000 my output should be [2,4000] and [1,2000] which is **[2,1]**

Here is my code

```
import itertools

def optimalUtilization(maximumOperatingTravelDistance,
                       forwardShippingRouteList, returnShippingRouteList):
    result=[]
    t1=[]
    t2=[]
    for miles in forwardShippingRouteList:
        t1.append(miles[1])

    for miles in returnShippingRouteList:
        t2.append(miles[1])

    result.append(t1)
    result.append(t2)
    total_sum=set()

    for element in list(itertools.product(*result)):
        if sum(element)<=maximumOperatingTravelDistance:
            total_sum.add(sum(element))

    total_sum=sorted(total_sum,reverse=True)
    return optimalUtilizationhelper(total_sum[0],
                       forwardShippingRouteList, returnShippingRouteList)


def optimalUtilizationhelper(maximumOperatingTravelDistance,
                       forwardShippingRouteList, returnShippingRouteList):
    dist_dict={}
    for carid,miles in forwardShippingRouteList:
        dist_dict.update({miles:carid})

    result=[]

    for carid,miles in returnShippingRouteList:
        if (maximumOperatingTravelDistance-miles) in dist_dict:
            result.append(list((dist_dict[maximumOperatingTravelDistance-miles],carid)))

    return result
```

Is there a better pythonic way to do this ?

Driver code

```
print(optimalUtilization(20,
                [[1,8],[2,7],[3,14]],
                [[1,5],[2,10],[3,14]]))
```

Comment: That's not a list of tuples. It's almost two separate tuples of lists, but there's a stray  `]` that makes it not valid as that, either. Can you edit this to show us the actual value that you have so we don't have to guess?

Comment: @vash_the_stampede There's no `3700` anywhere. There's a list of `[3, 7000]`; is that what's confusing you?

Comment: oh my makes sense its the spacing I'm tired :(

Comment: Anyway, if you have working code and you're just looking for ways to improve it, that's probably a question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not Stack Overflow. (But read [their help](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to make sure it's on-topic before posting there, rather than trusting some guy who's only got 341 rep on that site…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is more concise and linear wrt to the number of combinations:

```
from itertools import product

def optimalUtilization(n, l1, l2):
    # all (index1, index2, sum) triplets where sum is at most n
    res = [(a[0], b[0], a[1]+b[1]) for a, b in product(l1, l2) if a[1]+b[1] <= n]
    m = max(res, key=lambda x: x[2])[2]  # max sum <= n
    return [x[:2] for x in res if x[2] == m]

>>> optimalUtilization(20, [[1,8],[2,7],[3,14]], [[1,5],[2,10],[3,14]])
[(3, 1)]
```

Whether it is more readable or more Pythonic, is certainly debatable :)

**Update:** No more sorting and grouping needed.

Comment: How fast is this ? For me the complexity is n^2logn

Comment: I haven't timed it with large inputs. Why don't you try it?

Comment: @Rohit I have updated my answer. It should be asymptotically optimal. You can't be better than `O(N)` on the size of the `product`.

Comment: Are you saying itertools.product does O(n) operation?

Comment: @Rohit No. It obviously is O(n*m). n*m is hte size of the product I am referring to.